# How do I get third party jQuery plugins to work with Drupal?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the Slider Revolution jQuery plugin (from ThemePunch) on my Drupal site to create a slider on the front page.

I cannot for the life of me figure how to get this working. I have manually built a simple HTML page (outside of Drupal) to check the plugin and it works flawlessly, I just cannot seem to get it working in Drupal.

*Drupal version: 7*

*Slider Revolution version: 4.1.2*

Instructions for Slider Revolution: http://pastebin.com/gxNSV4hh

My theme is using *jQuery 1.9.0*

I have added into ***mytheme*.info**:

```
scripts[] = js/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js
scripts[] = js/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js
```

I have added to my front page:

```
<div class="tp-banner-container">
<div class="tp-banner" >
    <ul>
        <!-- SLIDE  -->
        <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500" >
            <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
            <img src="/sites/all/themes/sure2sell/js/rs-plugin/images/slidebg1.jpg"  alt="slidebg1"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
            <!-- LAYERS -->
            <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
            <div class="tp-caption lightgrey_divider skewfromrightshort fadeout"
                data-x="85"
                data-y="224"
                data-speed="500"
                data-start="1200"
                data-easing="Power4.easeOut">My Caption
            </div>
            ...

        </li>
        <!-- SLIDE  -->
        <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1000" >
            <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
            <img src="/sites/all/themes/sure2sell/js/rs-plugin/images/darkblurbg.jpg"  alt="darkblurbg"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
            <!-- LAYERS -->
            <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
            <div class="tp-caption lightgrey_divider skewfromrightshort fadeout"
                data-x="85"
                data-y="224"
                data-speed="500"
                data-start="1200"
                data-easing="Power4.easeOut">My Caption
            </div>
            ...
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using **Tracking Code module** I have added (before ***/body***) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
    {
      delay:9000,
      startwidth:1170,
      startheight:500,
      hideThumbs:10
    });
  });
</script>
```

Slider Revolution file ***jquery.themepunch.revolution.js*** is structured like:

```
(function(jQuery,undefined){

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    // THE REVOLUTION PLUGIN STARTS HERE //
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    jQuery.fn.extend({

    // OUR PLUGIN HERE :)
    revolution: function(options) {
    ...........
    ...........
    }})

})(jQuery);
```

Slider Revolution file ***jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js*** is structured like:

```
(function(t){"use strict";var e=t.GreenSockGlobals||t;if(!e.TweenLite){
    ..........
    ..........
);

(function(e,t){
    ..........
    ..........
})(jQuery)
```

How do I go about implementing this in Drupal? I believe Drupal expects jQuery/Javascript to be in a specific format (https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility) but I really don't know where to start with this. JS/jQuery really isn't my thing so I'm unsure what needs changed/added to make this compatible with Drupal.

**Update:** it works flawlessly, even with jQuery 1.7 : http://build.kaipee.co.uk/drupaltest/

Looks like it's an issue with my site/theme :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Managing Javascript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722) for the full details, but basically you're looking for something like this:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.sliderRevolution = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.tp-banner', context).once('sliderRevolution', function() {
        $(this).revolution({
          delay:9000,
          startwidth:1170,
          startheight:500,
          hideThumbs:10
        });
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: I've added that snippet to my front page but it doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to customise it to fit your exact site setup, the above is an abstract example. Check for JS errors on the console, then set about fixing em!

Comment: Are you saying that the Slider Revolution script doesn't need altered in any way? The only thing I need to tweak would be the snippet at the end of <body> ?

Comment: Quite a lot of the script errors are "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Comment: _Are you saying that the Slider Revolution script doesn't need altered in any way?_ You'd need to ask the developers of the plugin for that information, I wouldn't know. We can only cover questions directly related to Drupal here, we couldn't help you re-write an existing JS plugin for integration. The assumption I made was that the plugin works just like any other jQuery plugin, in which case the above (generic) method of invoking it would definitely work. This is the method core and contributed modules use to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Suffice to say that the above code couldn't cause "quite a lot" of errors, certainly not the errors you're seeing there. So it's likely you have other JS syntax problems/errors happening in the page, stopping the new code from being fired

Comment: So there may not be a way to simply implement any third party jQuery scripts onto a page, as simple as it would be when manually building an HTML file? All plugins/scripts need to be rewritten to suit Drupal?

Comment: It depends on each individual one, of course, but no - generally speaking, jQuery plugins don't need to be re-written for Drupal. Drupal is the backend, the front end is HTML, CSS and Javascript, so what works in one framework will by definition work in another if the same code is used. It sounds like you have JS problems not related to this though. Remove this code from your page - have all the JS errors gone? If not, you need to fix those up before your plugin code will ever have a chance to be run

Comment: I would say that *most* jQuery plugins don't need to be rewritten for Drupal.  Older ones may not use the current pattern of using a closure w/ no-conflict mode (this could be the root of your problem based on a comment a few up).  Also, Drupal ships be default with a old version of jQuery.  Newer plugins may assume a newer version.  The jQuery Update module can help with this, to an extent.

Comment: Thanks @Clive I performed a quick Drupal install on my own dev site and everything worked without a hitch, simply installed jQuery Update module and created a basic (full HTML) node.

Now I have the arduous task of trying to figure out/fix the main site/theme - which sucks even more because I'm not up to speed with jQuery/Js (and how Drupal expects it).